# SQL Server 2005 XML Query problem with ".exist" method

Tags: sql-server-2005, xquery

I have this XML Query in SQL Server 2005:

**`SElECT XmlField FROM tablename WHERE xmlField.exist('(/Root/Name[id="10")[1]') = 1`**

However, I want to replace the value "10" with a parameter that I pass to the Stored Procedure. How do I achieve this? I have tried using "@variablename" but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want to have something like

```
SELECT XmlField FROM tablename WHERE xmlField.exist('(/Root/Name[id="{ sql:variable("@variablename") }")[1]') = 1
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254(v=SQL.100).aspx for how to access variables and columns in XQuery in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your response. I have tried your suggestion but am getting an error message. This is the exact line of code am using:

`...WHERE Result_XML.exist('(/Root/Name[id="{sql:variable("@myId")}"])[1]') = 1`

I have declared and assigned a value to the variable `@myId` before this line of code
And I get this error message:

`Msg 9303, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
XQuery [Staff_Process_Triggers.Result_XML.exist()]: Syntax error near '@', expected ']'.`

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes of hair pulling...i found an answer...

`Result_XML.exist('(/Root/Name[id="{sql:variable("@myId")}"])[1]') = 1`

should be written as

`Result_XML.exist('(/Root/Name[id=(sql:variable("@myId"))])[1]') = 1`

I replaced the **"{** and **}"** with **(** and **)** to enclose the **sql:variable** keyword.

Comment: Maybe you can even leave the ( and ) away. Maybe the enclosing in "{ and }" that I took from the MSDN documentation is only necessary for construction of XML, not for XPath comparisons.

Comment: You are right Frank, the ( and ) are not necessary, it still works without them. Thanks again for your responses. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing I found out about by many many trials: if your variable is a char value, if you declare it in your sql statement, it should be varchar, not char.

This sql didn't return any results:

```
DECLARE @myparam char(50)
SET @myparam = 'someval'
...
WHERE 
t.c.exist('/root/child[text() = sql:variable("@myparam ")]') = 1
```

But this did:

```
DECLARE @myparam varchar(50)
SET @myparam = 'someval'
...
WHERE 
t.c.exist('/root/child[text() = sql:variable("@myparam ")]') = 1
```

Maybe this is obvious, but I spent some time before I figured the reason why no records would be returned.